# Linear Algebra about finding inner product of arbitrary polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are arbitrary polynomials of degree at most 2.

$\langle f,g\rangle=f(-2)g(-2)+f(0)g(0)+f(1)g(1)$

$f(x)=4x^2+4x-5$ and $g(x)=3x^2-6x-5$

find $\langle f,g\rangle$
and the angle between $\langle f,g\rangle$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The inner product is clearly defined in the question. What did you try?

Comment: To get you started: $f(-2) = 4(-2)^2 + 4(-2) - 5 = 16 - 8 - 5 = 3$. Try similar calculations to find $f(0), f(1), g(-2), g(0),$ and $g(1)$. You can then find $\langle f, g \rangle$.